# get warnings.warn('User provided device_type of \'cuda\', but CUDA is not available. Disabling') while train yolov5 model

Tags: pytorch, torch, yolov5

I am trying to train yolov5 model with colab
with this code : https://colab.research.google.com/drive/17o6Ci-x8hIMhWXXzxRQcxvB5MfvjEeDV?usp=sharing

```
`!python train.py --img 415 --batch 16 --epochs 30 --data dataset.yaml --device cpu --weights yolov5s.pt --cache`
```

I mention --device cpu but also I get same message
`warnings.warn('User provided device_type of \'cuda\', but CUDA is not available. Disabling')`

Comment: Perhaps this would be better as an issue on their repo rather than a question on stackoverflow.